# Nebular: Creating a new custom theme with javascript (NbJSThemesRegistry)

Tags: nebular

I want to dynamically create a theme for a user using the data that comes from the backend.

As I can see NbJSThemesRegistry has a method for this purpose:

```
 /**
  * Registers a new JS theme
  * @param config any
  * @param themeName string
  * @param baseTheme string
  */
  register(config: any, themeName: string, baseTheme: string): void;
```

I created MY_THEME, added it with NbJSThemesRegistry and tried to swith theme

```
const palette = {
    primary: '#3366ff',
    success: '#00d68f',
    info: '#0095ff',
    warning: '#ffaa00',
    danger: '#ff3d71'
};
const MY_THEME = {
    name: 'my-theme',
    base: 'default',
    variables: {
    fontMain: 'Open Sans, sans-serif',
    fontSecondary: 'Raleway, sans-serif',
    bg: '#222b45',
    bg2: '#1a2138',
    bg3: '#151a30',
    bg4: '#101426',
    border: '#222b45',
    border2: '#1a2138',
    border3: '#151a30',
    border4: '#101426',
    border5: '#101426',
    fg: '#8f9bb3',
    fgHeading: '#ffffff',
    fgText: '#ffffff',
    fgHighlight: palette.primary,
    layoutBg: '#1b1b38',
    separator: '#1b1b38',
    primary: palette.primary,
    success: palette.success,
    info: palette.info,
    warning: palette.warning,
    danger: palette.danger,
    primaryLight: '#598bff',
    successLight: '#2ce69b',
    infoLight: '#42aaff',
    warningLight: '#ffc94d',
    dangerLight: '#ff708d'
    }
}

this.nbJSThemesRegistry.register(MY_THEME, 'my-theme', 'default');
this.themeService.changeTheme('my-theme');
```

And then my css brokes. I see that body has class 'nb-theme-my-theme', but there are no custom css properties.

Сan anyone help me with this issue?